# В какую папку кинуть стикеры из телеграм что бы использовать в python

Tags: python, telebot

В какую папку кинуть стикеры из телеграм чтобы использовать в python типа static/welcome.webp? Я создавал на диске D: папки и кидал туда стикеры, но при включении бота пишет что директория стикера не найдена

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('D:/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
```

как решить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не нужно никуда ничего сохранять, стикеры можно отправлять по айди. `message.answer_sticker('id_sticker')`

Comment: В какую хотите, лишь бы путь был прописан правильный.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin храни тебя бог

Comment: Можно сделать
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

А дальше отправлять файлы по названию которые находятся в той же папке что и код
sti = open('welcome.webp', 'rb')

Answer (score 1):

► ***Любые файлы в своем боте вы можете отправлять через ID файла.***

https://vk.com/@python_geek-otpravka-foto-pytelegrambotapi - тут подробно об этом

Для начала вы должны **получить ID стикера**. Используйте в боте этот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text','sticker']) # Обработка стикеров и текста
def stick(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ID этого стикера:\n' + message.sticker.file_id) # Отправляем стикер
```

Далее код откинет вам **нужный ID**. *Вы его сохраняете* в (возможно) БД и отправка будет такая:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def stick(message):
    if message.text == 'мяучку в чат':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, random.choice(['id1', 'id2', 'id3']))
        # Отправитель мяучек в чат. Можно не рандом, а просто оставить один ID, как текст типа
```